# How do I make a binary translator?

Tags: java

So the code I have only works for a binary code that's 16 numbers long, but how do I make it work for ones that may be longer?

Here is what I have for the method:

```
public String binaryToText(String binary)
{
    int value = 1;
    String letter = "";
    String eightBitCode = "";
    int numberValue = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 7; i > 0; i--)
    {
        eightBitCode = eightBitCode + binary.charAt(i);
       
        if (binary.charAt(i) == '1')
        {
            numberValue = numberValue + value;
           
        }
        value = value * 2;
    }
    if (numberValue == 65)
    {
        letter = letter + "A";
    }
    if (numberValue == 66)
    {
        letter = letter + "B";
    }
    if (numberValue == 67)
    {
        letter = letter + "C";
    }
    if (numberValue == 68)
    {
        letter = letter + "D";
    }
    if (numberValue == 69)
    {
        letter = letter + "E";
    }
    if (numberValue == 70)
    {
        letter = letter + "F";
    }
    if (numberValue == 71)
    {
        letter = letter + "G";
    }
    if (numberValue == 72)
    {
        letter = letter + "H";
    }
    if (numberValue == 73)
    {
        letter = letter + "I";
    }
    if (numberValue == 74)
    {
        letter = letter + "J";
    }
    if (numberValue == 75)
    {
        letter = letter + "K";
    }
    if (numberValue == 76)
    {
        letter = letter + "L";
    }
    if (numberValue == 77)
    {
        letter = letter + "M";
    }
    if (numberValue == 78)
    {
        letter = letter + "N";
    }
    if (numberValue == 79)
    {
        letter = letter + "O";
    }
    if (numberValue == 80)
    {
        letter = letter + "P";
    }
    if (numberValue == 81)
    {
        letter = letter + "Q";
    }
    if (numberValue == 82)
    {
        letter = letter + "R";
    }
    if (numberValue == 83)
    {
        letter = letter + "S";
    }
    if (numberValue == 84)
    {
        letter = letter + "T";
    }
    if (numberValue == 85)
    {
        letter = letter + "U";
    }
    if (numberValue == 86)
    {
        letter = letter + "V";
    }
    if (numberValue == 87)
    {
        letter = letter + "W";
    }
    if (numberValue == 88)
    {
        letter = letter + "X";
    }
    if (numberValue == 89)
    {
        letter = letter + "Y";
    }
    if (numberValue == 90)
    {
        letter = letter + "Z";
    }
    //0        1      0      0     1     0     0    0
    //128     64     32     16     8     4     2    1
    i = 8;
    int h = 0;
    numberValue = 0;
    for (int j = 8; j < binary.length(); j++)
    {
       
        numberValue = 0;
        value = 1;
        j = j + 7;
        eightBitCode = "";
        h = binary.length() - 1;
        for (i = i; i < binary.length(); i++)
        {
            if (h == 7)
            {
                break;
            }
            eightBitCode = eightBitCode + binary.charAt(h);
            if (binary.charAt(h) == '1')
            {
                numberValue = numberValue + value;
            }
            value = value * 2;
            h = h - 1;
        }
    }
    if (numberValue == 65)
    {
        letter = letter + "A";
    }
    if (numberValue == 66)
    {
        letter = letter + "B";
    }
    if (numberValue == 67)
    {
        letter = letter + "C";
    }
    if (numberValue == 68)
    {
        letter = letter + "D";
    }
    if (numberValue == 69)
    {
        letter = letter + "E";
    }
    if (numberValue == 70)
    {
        letter = letter + "F";
    }
    if (numberValue == 71)
    {
        letter = letter + "G";
    }
    if (numberValue == 72)
    {
        letter = letter + "H";
    }
    if (numberValue == 73)
    {
        letter = letter + "I";
    }
    if (numberValue == 74)
    {
        letter = letter + "J";
    }
    if (numberValue == 75)
    {
        letter = letter + "K";
    }
    if (numberValue == 76)
    {
        letter = letter + "L";
    }
    if (numberValue == 77)
    {
        letter = letter + "M";
    }
    if (numberValue == 78)
    {
        letter = letter + "N";
    }
    if (numberValue == 79)
    {
        letter = letter + "O";
    }
    if (numberValue == 80)
    {
        letter = letter + "P";
    }
    if (numberValue == 81)
    {
        letter = letter + "Q";
    }
    if (numberValue == 82)
    {
        letter = letter + "R";
    }
    if (numberValue == 83)
    {
        letter = letter + "S";
    }
    if (numberValue == 84)
    {
        letter = letter + "T";
    }
    if (numberValue == 85)
    {
        letter = letter + "U";
    }
    if (numberValue == 86)
    {
        letter = letter + "V";
    }
    if (numberValue == 87)
    {
        letter = letter + "W";
    }
    if (numberValue == 88)
    {
        letter = letter + "X";
    }
    if (numberValue == 89)
    {
        letter = letter + "Y";
    }
    if (numberValue == 90)
    {
        letter = letter + "Z";
    }
    return letter;
}
```

What do I need to fix? I have tried so many things but nothing works, I seriously need some help. (Note: I sometimes try to print out some things to help me find where somethings going wrong but here I don't know what's wrong

Comment: I think you're approaching this from completely the wrong way.  Here you can only have capital latin letters, but there are so many more characters in unicode.  I would start [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#%3Cinit%3E(byte%5B%5D)).  Think about how you might turn the input string into a byte array.

Comment: What is a 'binary translator'? This code doesn't do anything intelligible. Edit the question to indicate what you're trying to do, for example with a few examples of 'turn this string into this string'.

Comment: "Binary translator: translates binary into text."

Answer (score 2):

```
String byteString = "01000001";
int decimal = Integer.parseInt(byteString, 2);
System.out.println("decimal: " + decimal);
char letter = (char) decimal;
System.out.println("letter: " + letter);
```

Output:

```
decimal: 65
letter: A
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [Reto's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65585189/6405362) will dramatically simplify your code, but still only parse a byte at a time. So, I would wrap that up in a single **parseByte(String byteStr)** method. Then, loop through your whole binary string in intervals of 8 using a simple for loop. The final code will look like this.

```
     public class BinaryParser {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            BinaryParser parser = new BinaryParser();
            System.out.println(parser.parseString("010010000110010101101100011011000110111100100000010101110110111101110010011011000110010000100001"));
        }

        public String parseString(String binaryStr) {
                String result = "";
                // note the i += 8, which will add 8 to i each iteration.
                for (int i = 0; i < binaryStr.length(); i += 8) {
                        String byteStr = binaryStr.substring(i, i+8);
                        result += parseByte(byteStr);
                }
                return result;
        }

        // Courtesy of Reto. See link above.
        public char parseByte(String byteStr) {
                int decimal = Integer.parseInt(byteStr, 2);
                char letter = (char) decimal;
                return letter;
        }

    }
```

And it will output

```
    Hello World!
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a string of bits to their ASCII equivalent you can do the following.

```
String bits = "0101010001101000011010010111001100"+
        "1000000111011101100001011100110010000001100010"+
        "01101001011011100110000101110010011110010010111000001010";
```

- get the byte, 8 bits at a time.
- convert to an `int` and then cast that to a `char` and print it
- reduce the string of bits by 8 and repeat until the string is empty.

```
public static String convert(String bits) {
    if (bits.length() % 8 != 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "String length must be divisible by 8");
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (!bits.isEmpty()) {
        String byt = bits.substring(0, 8);
        sb.append((char) (Integer.valueOf(byt, 2).intValue()));
        bits = bits.substring(8);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Returns

```
This was binary.
```

Comment: How would I do this in a return metho d?